# Django Admin autocomplete off

Tags: django, autocomplete

I am Trying to remove auto complete from the text fields in the django admin interface. I have not been able to figure out any way to do this in the admin. 
How can i set autocomplete="off" attribute on admin forms. Also is it possible to set autocomplete="off" attribute on individual admin fields.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me. Just added it to my admin.py

```
from django.forms import TextInput
from django.db import models

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off', 'class':'vTextField'})},
        models.IntegerField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off', 'class':'vIntegerField'})},
        models.URLField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off', 'class':'vURLField'})},
    }
```

Comment: I found for the latest version of Chrome (v46) I had to use
`models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'false',
                                                      'class': 'vTextField'})}`

Comment: when you change autocomplete option in inspect mode, it still completes... I couldn't find a proper solution...

Answer (score 0):

New versions of Chrome and Mozilla doesn't work with `autocomplete="off"` attribute. In my case I used a form for the additional password field. So my solution looks like this:

**forms/form_file.py**

```
password_field = forms.CharField(
    required=False, label='Update password',
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'password', 'name': 'password'}
    )
)
```

Use the [js script](https://github.com/terrylinooo/jquery.disableAutoFill) solution. Update **base admin html**: add listed js to head. Also it is needed to change `change_form.html` form template and to add next fields:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('<your_form_id>').disableAutoFill({passwordFiled: '.password'});
</script>
```

In my case it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There several variants to set `autocomplete off` for individual fields but the shortest one is:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['needed_field'].widget.attrs.update({'autocomplete': 'off'})
        return form
```